# Asynchronous call in operation hook "loaded" mangles the result

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using loopback v3.0.0-alpha.2 and have created an application two models and have done the migration to a mysql database.

What I am trying to do now is to use the operation hook "loaded" to inject some more data from one model into another model when data is retrieved.

Before implementing the "loaded" hook, when I do a simple GET call on the endpoint for the first model, let's say I do receive two rows like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Some Name"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Some Other Name"
    }
]
```

To inject the data I tried something like the following:

```
MyModel.observe('loaded', function someFunction(ctx, next) {
    var MySecondModel = MyModel.app.models.MySecondModel;

    if (some_condition) {
        MySecondModel.findById(ctx.data.some_id).then(function (data) {
            ctx.data.some_property = data.some_property;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            next(err);
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

So, under some condition, I want to lookup data from the second model and inject one of its properties into the original context. Strangely, when I run this and the "loaded" hook is called (and the condition is true), the result becomes mangled like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Some Other Name"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Some Other Name",
        "some_property": "some_value"
    }
]
```

As you can see, the data is duplicated into the first row. Looking into "dao.js" from the "loopback-datasource-juggler" package, I found the "DataAccessObject.find" function in particular into the "allCb" function and its "async.forEach" loop on the result set. If notifications are turned on, it first calls the "withNotify" method which after the "loaded" hook has been executed, calls the "buildResult" method.

When debugging the flow, the following calls happen:

1. withNotify (one the first row)
2. withNotify (one the second row)
3. buildResult (on the first row)
4. buildResult (on the second row)

The problem here seems to be that the variable "d" which is local to the "async.forEach" call gets overwritten in the second "withNotify" with the data of the second row and as it is used as a reference for the context data, even the first execution of "buildResult" will work on the *second* data set.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a proper way to enrich data after retrieving it from the data source?
2. If not, is there a way I can resolve this asynchronous problem?

Any help is much appreciated,
   Tobias.